# Google Data Studio JDBC connection to PostgreSQL integration with Sheets?

Tags: postgresql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, looker-studio

Google Apps Script JDBC doesn't support a connection to PostgreSQL directly but Google Data Studio supports a connection to PostgreSQL to pull data and build reports.  I've also heard they support a low-key export to .csv option.  Is it then possible to exploit the Data Studio Service in Google Apps Script to populate Google Sheets with that data, effectively creating a workaround?

All I need is a one-way access from PostgreSQL into Google Sheets by means of Google Apps Script, I do **NOT** expect to import anything back into my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the reference documentation, [the built-in Apps Script service for DataStudio](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio) does not allow you to pull data from a connected data source. It can be used to create connectors but its does not allow direct access to connected data sources.

However, you can try creating a custom API or server-less mirco-service in a language that supports PostgreSQL, and then expose that service as HTTP endpoints that you can call via URLFetchApp. You can leverage Google Cloud Functions to do this and write the mirco-service in either back-end Javascript(Node.js), Python or Go. This approach will take you well-outside the bounds of your typical GAS script, but it is a viable option.